# Convert SQL Integer into c# string for combobox (Access Database)

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, ms-access

The following code gives me an `IndexOutOfRange` error.
'Baujahr' is an integer column in my access-database.

```
cbFahrzeugBJ.Items.Add(reader["Baujahr"].ToString());
```

Here the reader:

```
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    cbFahrzeugBJ.Items.Add(reader["Baujahr"].ToString());
}
```

And the whole code of this procedure:

```
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Typ FROM Autos WHERE Hersteller = @FahrzeugHersteller AND Modell = @FahrzeugModell AND Typ = @FahrzeugTyp;";
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.Parameters.Add("@FahrzeugHersteller", SqlDbType.Text);
            command.Parameters["@FahrzeugHersteller"].Value = cbFahrzeugHersteller.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@FahrzeugModell", SqlDbType.Text);
            command.Parameters["@FahrzeugModell"].Value = cbFahrzeugModell.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@FahrzeugTyp", SqlDbType.Text);
            command.Parameters["@FahrzeugTyp"].Value = cbFahrzeugTyp.Text;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cbFahrzeugBJ.Items.Add(reader.GetInt32("Baujahr").ToString());
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
```

Comment: please show all relevant code.. where is this defined `cbFahrzeugTyp` have you used the debugger to step through the code..?

Comment: change your code and before the while loop add this 
`if (reader.HasRows){ }` do your while loop code inside the if block

Comment: @MethodMan that's pointless, If there are no rows, Read returns false,

Comment: Edited my question text. Debugger showed me IndexOutOfRange Error in line:cbFahrzeugBJ.Items.Add(reader["Baujahr"].ToString());

Comment: Your query is `SELECT DISTINCT Typ FROM ..` but then you're trying to access `Baujahr` which isn't in the select list.

Comment: also instead of having 2 lines 1 for parameter and the other for the parameter.value.. just append the `.value =` to the end of the lines it will make your code more readable. for example 
`command.Parameters.Add("@FahrzeugHersteller", SqlDbType.Text).value =cbFahrzeugHersteller.Text;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only including the `Typ` column in your result set. You will have to include `Baujahr` in your `SELECT` statement if you want to access it in your `DataReader`.

i.e:

```
 string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Typ, Baujahr FROM Autos WHERE Hersteller = @FahrzeugHersteller AND Modell = @FahrzeugModell AND Typ = @FahrzeugTyp;";
```